# Javascript: regular expression and .test

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JS - this might be easy for you guys to answer. I've been reading on regular expression but couldn't figure out the full meaning of this code:

I've been asked to write a myParseInt method with the following rules:

- It should make the conversion if the given string only contains a
  single integer value (and eventually spaces - including tabs, line
  feeds... - at both ends).
- For all other strings (including the ones representing float values),
  it should return NaN.
- It should assume that all numbers are not signed and written in base
  10.

The answer is:

```
function myParseInt ( str ) { return /^\s*\d+\s*$/ . test (str) ? + str :  NaN; }
```

(please correct me if I'm wrong!) But I sort of understand the first and last part (`/^\s*`  and `\s*$`) where it matches the beginning and end of str input with white space character. The `\d+` part matches digit characters 1 or more times.

The `.test(str)` part matches the str with the stated regular expressions and gives it a true or false value -

but why is there ? after `.test(str)`, then `+ str: NaN;`? I am unsure what does the `?` do, the `:` syntax. I know it has something to do with if it doesn't match, gives `NaN`. But I am trying to get clarifications regarding the syntax which I couldn't find on MDN.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The ? is a ternary operation.
You write a condition that returns true/false followed by a question mark, then what to return for truthy and falsy.
It is taken from C.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator